# How do I get my emulator to respect the hw.lcd.density/Abstracted LCD Density value of 256, reports as 240

Tags: android, layout, android-emulator, dpi

I created an AVD trying to emulate a qHD display: 540 pixels x 960 pixels with 256 dpi (hw.lcd.density or Abstracted LDC Density).

But when I do this:

```
Log.i("onCreate()",""+getResources().getDisplayMetrics().toString()); 
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
Log.i("onCreate()",dm.toString());
```

I get:

```
DisplayMetrics{density=1.5, width=540, height=960, scaledDensity=1.5, xdpi=240.0, ydpi=240.0}
DisplayMetrics{density=1.5, width=540, height=960, scaledDensity=1.5, xdpi=240.0, ydpi=240.0}
```

Density is reported as 240. Is that due to Android bucketing everything into 120, 160, 240, 320 dpi regardless of what the actual is? Or is it due to something else in my config?

Is this just an emulator thing or will I get the same on a real device?

Bonus question: Will my layout dimensions specified in dip (or dp) scale to the real dpi or to a bucketed dpi?

Comment: You say you changed the Abstracted LCD Density field in your emulator properties to 256?

Comment: @Fraggle Whether you used Built-in or you gave Resolution for creating AVD?

Comment: I did not use Built-in, I specified 540x960 as the resolution, then in the Hardware Property section (of the Create AVD screen) I clicked edited the Abstracted LCD Density to say 256. When I invistigate the details of the AVD it reports this as hw.lcd.density=256.

Comment: Well I think I answered one of my questions: Will my layout dimensions in dp scale to the real dpi or the bucketed dpi?; The answer (at least on an old Moto Droid) is the bucketed dpi. Moto droid has 265dpi but scales images specified in dps using the 240 bucket. This sucks (a lot) because basically images are not scaled properly (IMO).